# Use L'Hopital's rule to show that $\lim_{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \ell$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, be both differentiable. Suppose that $\lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \rightarrow + \infty} g(x) = 0$, that $g'(x) ≠ 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} = \ell \in \mathbb{R}$. Show that

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow+\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}= \ell$$

I'm immediately thinking L'Hopital's rule, and investigating when x tends to an element of $\mathbb{R}$. I just learnt this however, how would I go forth to use this (assuming I do actually need to use L'Hopital's rule)?

Comment: What about substituting variables $y=1/x$ and using usual L'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: i'm confused - what would y be in place of?

Comment: What I mean is that $\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{y\to 0^+}\frac{f(1/y)}{g(1/y)}$. You can then apply L'Hopital in the second limit.

Comment: I see, thanks! What inspired you to use 1/y?

Comment: It is simply a nice function which "maps $\infty$ to a real number". We could have used $\arctan(x)$ or $\frac{x^3}{\pi-3x^3}$ instead, and the procedure would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$F: x  \mapsto f(\frac{1}{x}) $$ and

$$G:x  \mapsto g(\frac{1}{x}).$$

with$ \;\;F(0)=G(0)=0$.

put $t=\frac{1}{x}$.

we have

$$\frac{F(x)}{G(x)}=\frac{f(t)}{g(t)}$$

and

$$\frac{F'(x)}{G'(x)}=\frac{  -t^2f'(t)   }{ -t^2g'(t)    }=\frac{ f'(t)  }{  g'(t)  }.$$

So,   l'Hopital rule at $x=0$ works also

at the  $t=\infty$

if $\lim_{t\to\infty}$
$f(t)=\lim_{t\to\infty}g(t)=0$.